# Xcode 6 application crash log

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, logging, crash-log

Is there any way to see the list of crash logs after Xcode  application crash (I don't need device crash log)? Or at least, is there any log with some similar info about Xcode app ?

Comment: You want the crash log for Xcode.app itself, not the app you are developing?

Comment: @NobodyNada Yeap, exactly , for Xcode.app...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find Mac Applications (including XCode) crash logs here: `~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/`

Answer (score 1):

Open Console.App, it will show you every crash you've ever had. Plus some pretty neat console info.

But this isn't an iOS dev question..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Crashlytics? It will show the stack trace once it has crashed.

Comment: No, I haven't...I just need log from previous crashes...Not a tool for analyzing crashes . I am not sure, but when Xcode crashes, there is a report, ignore and one more button...I think that third button says something like view crash log or something...I just try to find that info if is stored somewhere...